# How can I run multiple functions sequentially, and stop all when any of them fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, deferred, sequential

I have multiple Javascript functions, each does some DOM manipulation and then runs an ajax request. I want to be able to run the first function, which manipulates the DOM and then fires its ajax request, then, when the ajax request finishes, I want to run the second function if the ajax request returned true, or stop execution of the rest of the functions and do some other DOM manipulation (like showing an error message).

I want these functions to run sequentially, one after the other, and only keep going if none of them returns false from their ajax request. If none of them returns false, then all of them should run and eventually I would do some manipulation I have inside my "always" callback.

How can I accomplish this?

My first thought was to use promises, to keep the code cleaner, but after several hours of reading I just can't get how to make this work.

Below is my current code, and this is what I get in my console when it executes:

```
inside test1
inside test2
inside test3
fail
[arguments variable from fail method]
always
[arguments variable from always method]
```

This is what I want to get in my console (note the missing "inside test3" string):

```
inside test1
inside test2
fail
[arguments variable from fail method]
always
[arguments variable from always method]
```

Here's the code:

```
(function($) {
    var tasks = {
        init: function() {
            $.when(
                this.test1(),
                this.test2(),
                this.test3()
            ).done(function() {
                console.log('done');
                console.log(arguments);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log('fail');
                console.log(arguments);
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log('always');
                console.log(arguments);
            });
        },

        test1: function() {
            console.log('inside test1');
            return $.getJSON('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler');
        },

        test2: function() {
            console.log('inside test2');
            // note the misspelled "typ" arg to make it fail and stop execution of test3()
            return $.getJSON('https://baconipsum.com/api/?typ=meat-and-filler');
        },

        test3: function() {
            console.log('inside test3');
            return $.getJSON('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler');
        }
    };

    tasks.init();
})(jQuery)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using promises does make this code far cleaner

Note: Promise/A+ promise .then and .catch callbacks only ever take one argument, so no need for looking at `arguments`, just use a single argument

This code (ES2015+) shows how easy

```
let p = Promise.resolve();
Promise.all([this.test1, this.test2, this.test3].map(fn => p = p.then(fn()))).then(allResults =>
```

alternatively, using array.reduce

```
[this.fn1, this.fn2, this.fn3].reduce((promise, fn) => promise.then(results => fn().then(result => results.concat(result))), Promise.resolve([])).then(allResults =>
```

In both cases, `allResults` is an array of (resolved) results from the `testN` functions

It creates a (resolved) promise to "start" the chain of promises

the Array#map chains each function (this.test1 etc) to be executed in .then of the previous result. The results of each `this.testn` promise are returned in a new array, which is the argument for `Promise.all`

if any of testN fail, the next wont be executed

```
var tasks = {
    init () {
        let p = Promise.resolve();
        Promise.all([this.test1, this.test2, this.test3].map(fn => p = p.then(fn())))
        .then(results => {
            console.log('done');
            console.log(results);
            return results; // pass results to next .then
        }).catch(reason => {
            console.log('fail');
            console.log(reason);
            return reason; // because I return rather than throw (or return a Promise.reject), 
            //the next .then can will get `reason` in it's argument
        }).then(result => {
            console.log('always');
            console.log(result);
        });
    },
    test1() {
        return $.getJSON('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler');
    },
    test2() {
        return $.getJSON('https://baconipsum.com/api/?typ=meat-and-filler');
    },
    test3() {
        return $.getJSON('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler').then(result => {
            if(someCondition) {
                throw new Error("sum ting wong");
                // or
                return Promise.reject(new Error("sum ting wong"));
            }
            return result;
        });
    }
};
tasks.init();
```

for the code in the question, you could simplify it further

```
var tasks = {
    init () {
        let p = Promise.resolve();
        const urls = [
            'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler',
            'https://baconipsum.com/api/?typ=meat-and-filler',
            'https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler'
        ];
        Promise.all(urls.map(url => p = p.then(() => $.getJSON(url))))
        .then(results => {
            console.log('done');
            console.log(results);
            return results; // pass results to next .then
        }).catch(reason => {
            console.log('fail');
            console.log(reason);
            return reason; // because I return rather than throw (or return a Promise.reject), 
            //the next .then can will get `reason` in it's argument
        }).then(result => {
            console.log('always');
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
};
tasks.init();
```

Comment: This looks like what I was after... although I'm not sure if fat arrow functions are supported the same way as regular anonymous functions are? I will try it out, but this looks really great! Thank you, @Jaromanda X

Comment: `=>` makes more concise code, and less hassle with what `this` is :p you can always transpile the above

Comment: I converted your code to "regular" JS, it runs but it doesn't log what I was expecting in the console: https://gist.github.com/andruxnet/11a0c2baa45e870fc449bac02cb66bf5

Comment: maybe I'm missing. something... I converted the code using https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: You know what? I'm sorry, it does return what I want, I just needed to add a console.log() before the $.getJSON() call, it correctly runs only the first two url requests, but the second fails (as it should). I will try to implement this with the rest of the code. Thanks again, @Jaromanda X

Comment: Do you think I could use an array of functions instead of an array of urls? How would that look like? Something like the updated gist? https://gist.github.com/andruxnet/11a0c2baa45e870fc449bac02cb66bf5

Comment: Ha! It looks like it works with functions instead of urls :)

Comment: Just to improve on this maybe, would it work a bit better with reduce?  You could  get rid of the Promise.all then...

`urls.reduce(url => p = p.then(() => $.getJSON(url))).then(results .... `

Comment: yes, I thought of that @ChrisPhillips - unless of course you actually want to process all the results in some way - you can still use reduce and get all the results of course, without Promise.all - for this code, I thought it was simpler as is

Comment: I've added code that uses `Array#reduce` instead of `Promise.all`, but still returns an array of all results - as I think this is required

Comment: I'm going to stick with the `Promise.all` technique for now, since it already works that way :) thanks!

Comment: @JaromandaX how can I make the ajax request return a rejected promise instead of just an error for a malformed url? The ajax request is supposed to do some backend stuff and return some data or an error, I want to make the promise fail when I got an error... I tried just using `return false` and `return true` but that doesn't halt execution of the next requests

Comment: I'll add some example code for making a promise fail

Comment: Thanks, @JaromandaX I actually got it working using this: `return new $.Deferred().reject( errorMessage ).promise();`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not as familar with jquery promises.

But this should work

```
(function ($) {
    var tasks = {
        init: function () {
            this.test1().done(this.test2).done(this.test3)
                .done(function () {
                    console.log('done');
                    console.log(arguments);
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    console.log('fail');
                    console.log(arguments);
                })
                .always(function () {
                    console.log('always');
                    console.log(arguments);
                });
        },

        test1: function () {
            console.log('inside test1');
            return $.getJSON('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler');
        },

        test2: function () {
            console.log('inside test2');
            // note the misspelled "typ" arg to make it fail and stop execution of test3()
            return $.getJSON('https://baconipsum.com/api/?typ=meat-and-filler');
        },

        test3: function () {
            console.log('inside test3');
            return $.getJSON('https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler');
        }
    };

    tasks.init();
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess it can work, and I would use this if I wouldn't think there is the possibility of adding more ajax requests, so I want the code to be easily extendable.. this solution would become a bit messy with several other callbacks

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, this chains the 3 promises you were creating together which is what you were asking about. I assume in your actual code you are doing more inside functions test1, test2, test3 besides looking up the json data.

What other changes were you looking for?

Comment: I mean, it works (or at least it should work as I can see it) but I want to be able to add more functions easily, chaining test1, test2, ..., test20 might look a bit messy and harder to maintain (what if I wanted to comment out some of those?) It's a good solution, but this code might get maintained in the future by other developers and I want to make it as easy as possible for them if I'm not around

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use promises - and perhaps you know this, but you can keep calling the next ajax request in the prevoius one's success block, like this:

```
(function($) {
    var tasks = {
        init: function() {
                    $.post(url_1, data_1, function(data,status){
            if(status == 'success')
            {
                $.post(url_2, data_2, function(data,status){
                    if(status == 'success')
                    {
                        // ... and the next Ajax request goes here, etc.
                    }
                    else {
                        // show error message if 2nd Ajax request fails
                    }
                }
            else {
                // show error message if 1st Ajax request failes
            }
        });
    });    
        }

    tasks.init();
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: welcome to the pyramid of doom or callback hell - imagine even just 10 urls :p

Comment: Actually the code in the question is shorter than what I actually have, the real code has around 8 ajax requests, and it's possible to add even more